# Upthrust constant with depth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure

A ball falls through a liquid at a constant speed. It is acted upon by three forces: an upthrust, a 
drag-force and its weight.

Which statement is correct?

A The drag-force increases with increasing depth.

B The drag-force is equal to the sum of the upthrust and weight.

C The upthrust is constant with increasing depth.

D The weight is greater than the sum of the drag-force and the upthrust

I'm confused between option A and C. I think answer is A as upthrust should change with depth. Correct answer is C

Comment: So state which you think is correct and why. Then people may respond...

Comment: Hi Asad and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, "upthrust" is more commonly referred to as "buoyant force". Buoyant force is determined by Archmiedes' principle and is equal in magnitude to the weight of the liquid displaced. Liquid is incompressible by definition so the density of liquid doesn't change with increasing depth. Neither does the volume of your object. (This question is poorly written because real life a ball would get slightly smaller with increasing depth but I'm going to ignore that in the spirit of the question.) Therefore the buoyant force stays constant with increasing depth.

The drag force on an object is a function of the object's speed, the object's drag coefficient, the object's cross-sectional area, and the density of the material producing the drag. None of these change as an object sinks into a liquid because a liquid's density (and most of its other properties except pressure) stay constant with depth.

In general, the properties of a liquid don't change much with depth except for pressure which increases linearly with depth.

Comment: @Isusr You first mention that buoyant force stays constant with increasing depth. And then at the end, you mention that it varies with depth. Please clarify.

Comment: @Zam Fixed. Thanks.